# iPod Touch will charge but won't play when connected to a Sony docking system

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

I bought a Sony ICF-CS15iP docking system and my iPod will charge when I connect it, but it will not play music through the speakers. This is my 3rd docking system and I have had the same problem with the others - it will charge but not play.  I'm assuming it is my iPod that has something wrong with it. Should I call Sony and or Apple?? Thanks!
Note* I have a 4th gen iPod Touch

Comment: Any luck? I called Sony and after a hour of talking to four different people they said they had no clue.

Comment: Well, as it is the third station bringing you the same problems, I rather think it is your iPod that causes the problems.

Comment: Just did the new update 6.01 & it still doesn't work it charges the iPod but won't play

Answer (score 2):

I found a product description on the Best Buy website:

> The ICF-CS15IP is Compatible with most iPod® and iPhone® models, including iPhone 4. Works with: iPod touch® 2nd, 3rd, & 4th generations, iPod nano® 3rd (video), 4th (video), 5th (video camera), & 6th generations, iPod classic®, iPhone® 4, iPhone 3GS, and iPhone 3G.

Your 4th generation iPod Touch is listed as supported by this device, so you should contact Sony and expect them to help you.

Comment: Thank you!! I just contacted them awhile ago, and they told me to update my iPod, but that seems to not have made a difference.........I will contact Apple soon. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just bought the sony ipod docking station for my daughter for Christmas.  Her IPOD Touch 4th generation will charge, but the music will not come out of the docking speakers.  My son has an older IPOD Touch and it worked fine.  I called Sony and they told me I had to reinstall the operating system on the IPOD touch 4th generation for it to work.  I went through the hassel of resetting back to factory settings.  Still did not work.

Comment: The IPOD 4th generation, however does work on our friend's BOSE docking station.

Comment: Ouch - Hopefully the sony rep has notes and can follow up with better advice once your trying a restore has eliminated an edge case. It's odd for the software to cause a dock connector to not provide audio out, but I'm sure some cases could be chalked up to that - but not the majority of them.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to test a docking station for operation is to test several iPhone / iPod that you know work with other dock connectors and see that they all work with your dock speakers.

The easiest way to test an iPod is to use it with several dock chargers and speakers.

Once you have done one of these tests it should be easy to know which piece isn't working reliably. Both Sony and Apple should be able to support you in these basic activities and once you know which item isn't working.

Also look for [Apple's MFi logo](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) to indicate that the device is designed to work with all Apple products as an indication that you won't need any extra apps or connectors to make things work. Lastly, peek into the physical connectors to be sure that lint or other problems are not lurking and making the electrical connection unreliable or impossible to be completed.

Answer (score 0):

My iPod Touch 4th Gen also doesn't work with this Sony model.  It does work with my similar, older Sony clock radio dock station though.  I downloaded the d-sappli app but that didn't help.  Going to return the Sony tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

There is an app you have to download to make it play. It popped up when I put it on there the very first time, and I accidentally hit ignore. Need info.

Comment: It would be surprising if a dock required an app to receive music over the standard dock connector - especially with [Apple's Made for iPod program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) that allows hardware manufacturers to ensure things work together out of the box.

Comment: The app you are looking for is probably https://itunes.apple.com/app/d-sappli/id416030022 which is referenced from http://store.sony.com/p/iPod-and-iPhone-Alarm-Clock/en/p/ICFCS15IPBLK